# OCMock asynchronous block callback

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I am building a small library to handle file upload and download operations for me and am trying to integrate a suite of tests into it.  Rather than using delegate callback methods, I am handling the asynchronous responses in a completion handler block like so:

```
  SyncKit *engine = [[SyncKit alloc] init];
  NSURL *localFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/justin/Desktop/FileTest.png"];

  [engine uploadFileWithFilename:@"FileTest.png" toRemotePath:@"/" fromLocalPath:localFilePath withCompletionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
      NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
      return;
    }

    NSLog(@"File uploaded and return JSON response = %@", response);
  }];
```

The underlying `uploadFileWithFilename...` method is like so:

```
- (void)uploadFileWithFilename:(NSString *)filename toRemotePath:(NSString *)remotePath fromLocalPath:(NSURL *)localPath withCompletionHandler:(SKCompletionHandler)handler
{
  if ((![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[localPath path]]))
  {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:localPath forKey:@"localPath"];
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:SKDropboxErrorDomain code:SKDropboxErrorFileNotFound userInfo:userInfo];
    handler(nil, error);
    return;
  }

  // path is the directory the file will be uploaded to, make sure it doesn't have a trailing /
  // (unless it's the root dir) and is properly escaped
  NSString *trimmedPath;
  if (([remotePath length] > 1) && ([remotePath characterAtIndex:[remotePath length] - 1] == '/')) 
  {
    trimmedPath = [remotePath substringToIndex:[remotePath length] - 1];
  } 
  else if ([remotePath isEqualToString:@"/"])
  {
    trimmedPath = @"//";
  }
  else 
  {
    trimmedPath = remotePath;
  }

  NSString *escapedPath = [NSString escapePath:trimmedPath];
  NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/files/dropbox%@", escapedPath];      
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@/%@%@", kSKProtocolHTTPS, kSKDropboxAPIContentHost, kSKDropboxAPIVersion, fullPath];

  NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:filename, @"file", nil];
  NSString *body = [params convertToURIParameterString];

  NSURL *url = nil;
  if ([body length] == 0)
  {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlString]];
  }
  else
  {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", urlString, body]];
  }

  __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
  request.delegate = self;
  request.requestMethod = kSKMethodPOST;

  [request addFile:[localPath path] forKey:@"file"];

  //
  // Dropbox uses OAuth to handle its authentication, so we need to pass along the requested
  // tokens and secrets so that we get our stuff back.
  //  
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *token = [defaults objectForKey:@"oauth_token"];
  NSString *secret = [defaults objectForKey:@"oauth_secret"];  

  [request buildPostBody]; 
  NSData *authBody = request.postBody; 

  NSString *header = OAuthorizationHeader(url, request.requestMethod, authBody, kOAuthConsumerKey, kOAuthConsumerSecret, token, secret);  
  [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:header];  

  [request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSDictionary *result = (NSDictionary *)[[request responseString] JSONValue];    
    [self.activeUploads removeObjectForKey:remotePath];
    handler(result, nil);
  }];

  [request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = request.error;
    [self.activeUploads removeObjectForKey:remotePath];
    handler(nil, error);
  }];

  [self.activeUploads setObject:request forKey:remotePath];

  [self.queue addOperation:request];
}
```

I saw [one example](http://petersteinberger.com/2010/10/how-to-mock-asihttprequest-with-ocmock-and-blocks/) where the guy was using a preprocessor define and injecting the OCMock into the actual codebase.  That seems wrong to me.

What would be the best strategy to test a piece of code like this?

Comment: In the above function, what does properly escaped path mean?

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't related specifically to OCMock so it may not be what you're looking for, but...

I would do something like this:

```
__block BOOL testPassed = NO;

[engine uploadFileWithFilename:@"FileTest.png" 
                  toRemotePath:@"/" 
                 fromLocalPath:localFilePath 
         withCompletionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
      return;
    }

    testPassed = YES;
  }];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                      beforeDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10]];

// make sure that testPassed is YES...
```

That way, you'd block until one of the callbacks made its way onto the main run loop.